# PCIe connector overhang

Tags: layout, pcie

There are precise mechanical requirements for PCIe cards. Along the top edge, there's a 1mm strip where copper and components are not allowed. If you're designing a PCIe card, and have connectors and switches along that top edge, are they allowed to overhang the edge of the PCB? Are they allowed to overhang the copper/component keepout area? If not, can you cut down the height of the card to let the switches and connectors overhang the PCB but stay inside the allowed envelope?

Comment: I'd have to read the specs. You should have done that already - what do they say?

Comment: There are (few) cases with guide rails on the top, both in full-height and half-height sizes. It should be possible to close such a case when your card is inserted without bending any connectors.